# How can I output a batch file to one line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm new to scripting so I need some help with this. I've searched for two days and cannot grasp this!

What I'm doing is scanning a directory for particular files and then counting the results and piping it to a file.

```
dir *.DONE | find "04338" /c >>04338.txt
```

So the results look like this:

```
14  
14  
(blank line for carriage return)
```

My application is trying to read this file and run commands against it using RegEx. That part works fine except the application does not assign variables using multi-line match properly... it will grab the data fine but I cannot output it properly.

Because of this I have to write all of the data to one line. Eventually I want it to look like this:

```
14,14,14,14,14,14,14
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it onto one line. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.DONE ^| find "04338" /c') do <nul set/p "=%%a,">>4338.txt
type 4338.txt
```

Remove one `,` at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you.

I get:

14,  

However, if I run this file again, I need it to append the results to the file.

If I run the batch again it still only gives me 14,.

Comment: I see, made an edit. Add at the end of all runs `echo(>>4338.txt`.