# Windows Batch file - Format CertUtil output and filename and size in single line

Tags: batch-file, certutil

My requirement is to create an output file with the following format:  `Filename,file size,checksum`

An example would be `abc.tar,1024 Bytes,052107adc8c42d6cf581bf81225ae6de`

#### Code

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
set OUTFILE="C:\Script\Batch_OUT.txt"

echo %OUTFILE%

echo Extracting Batch records to %OUTFILE% ...
echo pwd = `pwd`

cd C:\Script\TARS\

for %%f in (Batch_*.tar) do (  
(echo %%~nxf && echo %%~zf Bytes && certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5 | find /V    ":") >>%OUTFILE%  
) 

pause 2m
```

#### Output

```
Batch_one.tar 
778240 Bytes 
052107adc8c42d6cf581bf81225ae6de
```

#### Expected Outcome

```
Batch_one.tar,778240 Bytes,052107adc8c42d6cf581bf81225ae6de
```

Comment: No @DavidWinder I want to get the checksum also generated for the file.

Comment: Yes it is. Other problem, but same solution (writing without a `CRLF`). I "translated" it to your problem in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same trick as in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729241/how-can-i-output-a-batch-file-to-one-line), David Winder already linked in a comment:

```
...
for %%f in (test.txt) do (  
 (
   <nul set /p ".= %%~nxf,%%~zf Bytes," 
   certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5 | find /V ":"
 ) >>%OUTFILE%  
) 
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephan and David.... that about snippet worked ...I was always assigning set /p to a variable and had issues around !<variable-name>! ...but the above code helped me with the task..Thank you

Comment: Adding <nul set /p "=%%~dpnxA" & echo: after the certutil line generates an unwanted newline after the MD5 value. The nul set /p trick doesn't seem to work on the certutil line: I get a syntax error when I try using it there.

Comment: @RayWoodcock. a) You realize, `& echo:` produces a linebreak? (`<nul set /p "=%%~dpnxA" & echo:` has the very same effect as just `echo %%~dpnxA` or `echo %%~fA`)  b) the `set /p` trick works with a string, not with a command. Capture the output of the command with a `for /f` loop if you need it's output without a linebreak: `for /f %%a in ('certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5 ^| find /V ":"') do <nul set /p "=%%a"`

Comment: Yes, echo: is not the problematic break. With your suggestion, everything looks good except the hash does not appear. In case you were wondering, I'd have posted a separate question, but they semi-suspended me for not getting enough upvotes on my questions, and I didn't find another source that explained it as clearly as you did. Thanks for trying to help. I'll definitely welcome further suggestions. This question is closed, so I've posted the current status elsewhere: https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2022/04/03/dir-filename-hash-oneline/

Comment: You have a simple (copy and paste?) error: you don't have %%f. Replace it with %%A. Also you don't need the `set /p` trick, because all the desired information is present at the same time: `for %%A in (*) do (`, `for /f %%B in ('certutil -hashfile "%%A" SHA512 ^| find /V ":"') do echo %%~tA %%~zA %%B %%~fA`, `)`

Comment: That makes sense. Basically, use the inner FOR loop to accumulate all desired items of file information; then the end of that loop adds the desired newline. This works. I will be updating my post shortly. You have no idea how happy I am to get this sorted out. It has been a bottleneck. Thank you again.

Comment: Exactly. To write the output of the `certutil` without a linebreak with `set /p`, you need to capture the output with a `for /f` loop anyway. Then - why not use the captured string directly, instead of setting it to a variable to be able to use an awkward workaround..

Comment: New problem: the FOR loops seem very slow. I've been encouraged not to post further at StackOverflow, so the discussion continues elsewhere: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/193553-batch-slow-loops-produce-one-line-file-info-date-hash-etc.html#post2413352

Comment: Try `(for /r %%A in (*) do for /f %%B in ('certutil -hashfile "%%A" SHA512 ^| find /V ":"') do echo %%~tA %%~zA %%B %%~fA)>%OUTFILE%` (a single redirect instead of redirecting each line on its own)